# sonarqube dashboard view when run in incremental mode

Tags: sonarqube

I run sonar scan in incremental mode.

Do I have any option to see the result and indication when the last execution run in the sonarqube dashboard?

I found only the indication for full scan mode.

Thanks,
Shurik

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the (now deprecated) "incremental" mode does not push results to the server, so you will never be able to see dashboards with this mode.

Please read the ["Analysis Modes" documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Concepts#Concepts-AnalysisModes) to know more about this.